# Trouble with Installing Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, import, anaconda

I have tried several things, and I am experiencing many difficulties in trying to install keras to Python.

1. First, I tried by simply trying to import it into my Jupyter Notebook using the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b9e2c8277ae4> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.models import Sequential
      2 from keras.layers import Dense

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

2. Then, I tried importing tensorflow.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

This didn't work either, for I received a similar error as before.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-9d4e366b5092> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential #used for model building
      2 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout,Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D #used for model building

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

3. I finally tried to use the terminal through Anaconda. This failed as well.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:
```

I have Python 3.8, but apparently keras requires `python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']`. What can I do to import keras?

Comment: I'm no expert but it appears that keras just doesn't work for python 3.8 based on your last paragraph. Or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: @Maxijazz - yes it appears so, should I somehow revert my Python version????

Comment: I don't think error is due to version. Otherwise you would have got **UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment**  error

Comment: What can I do to fix this? I am very confused. @PranjalDoshi

Comment: From the logs it looks like keras and tensorflow are not installed. Are you sure that they are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, `keras` and `tensorflow` don't work well with Python 3.8. I would try reverting to Python 3.7.

Comment: No, this is not true, the problem is in Anaconda, which has not packaged Keras and TensorFlow (v 2.2) for Python 3.8, it is a packaging error in their side. Keras in particular works fine in Python 3.8